# Change product attribute textfield to textarea in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

We have one attribute that is a text field, but after using it we noticed it should be text area:/
Any way to change this, as it cannot be changed from the backend. Unfortunately we noticed text field cannot store all the text we use in it.

Please suggest me how it is possible.

Answer (score 8):

ong search we find out the solution of this problem:

**if you want to change textfield to textarea of magento product attribute**

Please take a backup before changes in database table and follows given steps

1) Please go to your database
2) look table eav_attribute
3) Select your attribute row
4) Change only two column value

- backend_type : change varchar to text
- frontend_input : text to textarea

5) Now check your attribute change textfield to textarea with old values of all products.

Answer (score 1):

The product attributes are saved into different database tables depending on their type. So no, you can't change this easily.

Your only way is to get all the existing values out of the table, save them temporary, remove the attribute, create a new attribute with the same settings but with type textarea and than save all the values again in the right table.

Answer (score 0):

@KapilGupta solution will leave garbage in your database. A cleaner solution would be exporting all the product data for this attribute to a csv file using Magento's export tool (or RapidFlow extension). Then remove the attribute and create a new one with the right settings, and import the data back in.